# How to parse and work on real time output in ruby?

Tags: ruby, bash, stream, tail

I would like to do a simple thing in ruby: enter in a server , launch a `tailf -f` command on a log file, and perform some operation on the stream of output. (like extract some info)

How can I do it in ruby?

If a use the backtick to execute the command, the output it is never returned, is there a data structure to old this continuos output?

Comment: Generally you just keep attempting to read from a file handle and it will produce data as more is available.

Comment: @tadman how can I read only the new data everytime?

Comment: All file-handles have pointers to their current position within the file. This will be at the last spot you successfully read data unless you close it.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way (and most Unix-y way) is to use the `-n` or `-p` arguments to the `ruby` command. From the man page (`man ruby`):

```
-n     Causes Ruby to assume the following loop around your script, which makes
       it iterate over file name arguments somewhat like sed -n or awk.

             while gets
               ...
             end
```

That's vague (and the "file name arguments" bit is misleading), so here's an example (let's call it `sum.rb`):

```ruby
BEGIN {
  sum = 0
}

sum += $_.to_i

END {
  puts "Sum: #{sum}"
}
```

What will happen when we run this script with `ruby -n` is, the code in the `BEGIN` block will run once, then the code outside the block will run for every line of input piped to Ruby—the line is stored in `$_`—and then the code in the `END` block will run.

Suppose we have a file with the following content (let's call it `data.txt`):

```
10
15
25
50
```

Now we can do this:

```
$ cat data.txt | ruby -n sum.rb
Sum: 100
```

What if we only want to sum the first two numbers? Use `head`!

```
$ head -2 data.txt | ruby -n sum.rb
Sum: 25
```

What if we want to print every number, in addition to the sum? Use `-p` (for "print") instead of `-n`:

```
$ head -2 data.txt | ruby -p sum.rb
10
15
Sum: 25
```

The `ruby` command is very powerful. For example, the `-a` option will **a**utomatically split each line into an array and put it in `$F`, so if your input has two columns the first column of each line will be in `$F[0]`, the second in `$F[1]`, and so on. I highly recommend typing `man ruby` and taking a few minutes to see what options are available. Here's a good blog post that goes over some of the features: http://arjanvandergaag.nl/blog/using-ruby-command-line-options.html

One last thing: For ease of use, I recommend adding a shebang line to the top of your script, e.g.:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env ruby -n
```

...and then using `chmod` to make your script executable (e.g. `chmod ug+x sum.rb`). This way your script can specify all of the arguments it needs and you can just do `cat data.txt | ./sum.rb`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [pty](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/pty/rdoc/PTY.html) module.

You will need to do something like this:

```
require 'pty'

cmd = "tail -f <path-to-your-log-file>"

begin
  PTY.spawn(cmd) do |stdout, stdin, pid|
    begin
      # print output to show how it works
      # you will need to extract your info from "line" variable below
      stdout.each { |line| print line }
    rescue Errno::EIO
      puts "This means the process has finished giving output"
    end
  end
rescue PTY::ChildExited
  puts "Child process exited!"
end
```

Comment: Not really necessary to fork out here, especially when this doesn't `shellescape` properly.

Comment: Spinning up the `tail` command in `-f` mode ls a really clunky way of doing this, Ruby can do the exact same thing using `File`. Secondly, if the path variable has a space in it, this command fails. You *need* to call [`shellescape`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/shellwords/rdoc/Shellwords.html#method-c-shellescape) on any arguments to the shell supplied by the user.

Answer (score 0):

```
f=File.open("path_to_log_file")
no_of_lines_per_fetch = 1
f.seek(0, no_of_lines_per_fetch)

def decision_making_function(data)
  #your logic
  puts "processing #{data}"
end

while true
  if (line=f.gets) != nil
    decision_making_function(line)
  end
end
```

Comment: It's pretty much this, but: `while true` can be `loop do` and comparing vs `nil` isn't necessary. Do `while (line = f.gets)`.